# how to convert int variables to string variables

Tags: c#, string, integer

I am currently splitting a string from a textbox that the user will fill with three numbers. Those numbers i want to be saved as seperate integers. Any help as to how to do this? Thanks for any help!

```
string[] count = txtPoemInput.Text.Split('/');  //Splitting values for keyword numbers

int Poem, Line, Word;

count[0] = Poem.ToString; // Example
count[1] = Line;          // Example
count[2] = Word;
```

Comment: So do you want co convert `string` to `int` or `int` to `string`? And what have you already tried?

Comment: I want to take my text box which is type string and split it into 3 different integer variables. I have tried Int32.Parse ive tried starting the variables as a string and then changing it to Ints.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do. Use Convert.ToInt32

```
Poem = Convert.ToInt32(count[0]);
Line = Convert.ToInt32(count[1]);
Word = Convert.ToInt32(count[2]);
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that thank you!

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception if the text entered is not numeric (or, at least, can't be parsed as a string). Use `int.TryParse` instead if you want to be defensive about it, or wrap it in a `try catch`:

Comment: my textbox is a masked text box so only numeric values can be entered but thanks

Comment: This is how I would go about it (opinion, I know). I don't see any easier way to go about converting the `string` values to `int`. This should work fine as long as the values being passed are numeric- which as OP has stated, they are.